# How to use GTK container remove for c

Tags: c, gtk

I'm using gtk container remove and it says that the container needs a reference to the widget but I'm unsure how to do this and was wondering if someone could show me how to do this. If it helps it's a button widget, thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

When you create a widget, the widget is initially said to be *floating*. "Floating" refers to the limbo that an object is in after it is created but before someone claims ownership of it by taking a reference. When you add the widget to a container, the container calls `g_object_ref_sink()` on the widget to get rid of the floating state and get a reference on the widget. After this, the reference count on the widget is 1. (If an object is not floating, `g_object_ref_sink()` will merely add a reference to the object.)

When you remove a widget from a container, the container calls `g_object_unref()` to remove that reference it took when you added the widget. But because the reference count on that widget was 1, the call to `g_object_unref()` will set the reference count to 0, and the widget will be destroyed.

Therefore, if you need to remove a widget from its parent container, but still keep it around (for instance, to put it in a new container), you first need to get a reference yourself with `g_object_ref()`.

As an example, to move a widget from one container to another, you would do

```
// get a reference on the widget so it stays alive
// I forget when you would want to use g_object_ref_sink() instead
g_object_ref(widget);
// remove the widget
gtk_container_remove(container, widget);
// add it to the other container
gtk_container_add(otherContainer, widget);
// the call to gtk_container_add() took a reference
// we are now done with ours
g_object_unref(widget);
```